# Already installed JSON Server But show message Command Not Found

Tags: npm, command, installation, json-server

I already installed in other computers by npm the json-server. But on my MacBook Pro the command was run with successful and when I will execute the command json-server db.json is showed the message:

[Errors Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3P8tX.png)
[image]

My versions:

[node -v and npm -v](https://i.stack.imgur.com/McmWZ.png)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did fix this following these steps:

https://gist.github.com/rcugut/c7abd2a425bb65da3c61d8341cd4b02d

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. Previously, I named the folder as json-server (same as the package name)
I changed the folder name and installed the package globally using
`npm install -g json-server`
It works perfectly fine now

Answer (score 0):

Made the same mistake using VS Code. Entered in terminal->>

```
$ json-server --watch data/db.json <<-
```

Got the classic ->>

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'data/db.json' <<-
```

Simple fix was to realize I needed to add the parent folder name in the terminal ->>

```
$ json-server --watch folder-name/data/db.json <<-
```

This opened a local host to my db.json file ->>

```
http://localhost:3000/projects <<-
```

Hope this helps someone that made the same simple mistake I did.

Answer (score -1):

I too got this issue. while working on a frontend project(vue).
I don't know why it happens but I found a way around / solution.

go to your pakage.json file.
go to "scripts" 
and add

```
   "scripts": {
     "fakeDB":"json-server --watch db.json"
 },
```

you can change "fakeDB" to what ever you want 
and "json-server --watch " is used to run your json db file
in my case its db.json